# Julia function naming: When should I append a bang?

Tags: coding-style, julia

The Julia style guide [says](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/style-guide/#append-to-names-of-functions-that-modify-their-arguments) that functions which "modify their arguments" should have their name end on a `!`.

However, what about:

1. functions that do modify their arguments, but return them to their original state before returning?
2. functions that return a `Task` which modifies the argument when executed?
3. functions that return such a `Task`, but when it is done, the arguments will have been restored to their original states?

Should their names end on a `!`?

---

As an example, consider [this module](https://github.com/lmshk/sandbox/blob/master/euler/lib/ExactCovers.jl) for finding [exact covers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_cover) using Knuth's [Dancing Links Algorithm](http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/papers/dancing-color.ps.gz). It implements a type `CoverSet` that can be populated with the subsets and then queried for the first exact cover:

```
set = CoverSet()
push!(set, [1, 2])
push!(set, [2, 3])
push!(set, [3, 4])
push!(set, [4, 1])

find_exact_cover(set) # returns [1, 3]
```

The `find_exact_cover` function temporarily modifies the data in `set` while searching for a solution, but by the time `find_exact_cover` returns, `set` will be in its original state. Should it be named `find_exact_cover!` instead?

Similarly, `exact_cover_producer` returns a `Task` that produces all exact covers, but when that `Task` is done, `set` will have been restored:

```
for cover in exact_cover_producer(set)
  println(cover) # prints [1,3] and [2,4]
end
# By now, set is restored.
```

Should it be `exact_cover_producer!`?

---

I am aware that this might be considered subjective, so let me clarify what I am asking for: I would like to know whether there is a convention on this in the Julia community, and ideally also examples from the standard library or any packages that use either style.

Comment: When I see a function without a bang in julia I assume that all the arguments I passed in will be unchanged after the call is done. What happens inside the function is not my concern.

Answer (score 2):

See e.g. the [discussion at Julia commit e7ce4cba44fa3b508fd50e0c3d03f6bc5a7a5032](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/e7ce4cba44fa3b508fd50e0c3d03f6bc5a7a5032): the current convention is that a function is *mutating* and hence has a `!` appended if it changes what one of its arguments would be `==` to.

(But there is some justification for slightly broader definitions as well; see the abovementioned discussion.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this does not quite answer my question. The argument under consideration might not even have a working `==` defined (like in my example). But even if we broaden the definition to *equal externally visible behavior* (via some defined interface), this does not answer any of my points, because it says nothing about *when* the equality should hold.
The part that gets closest is the one about concurrency, but that is vague and far from convention.

Anyway, this link is useful, so +1.